# Organizing a complex AngularJs app; controllers or services?

Tags: angularjs, events, iframe, module, code-organization

this is a bit complex question to explain so please bear with me!

I'm building an app that relays on user interaction (lots of events, clicks..) to create html elements on the DOM of an iframe (resides on the same domain).

[image: Sketch]

```
<div ng-controller="mainCTRL">
    <ul ng-controller="btnCTRL">
        <li ng-repeat="tool in tools">
            <a href="#" ng-click="toolClicked($index)">{{tool.text}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <iframe src="same-domain/iframe.html">
        <p>Sorry but your browser does not support iframes!</p>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

I'm trying to follow the best practices as much as I could but have an issue with the concept of services and controllers on this project; in the iframe, I don't want to put any angularjs directives or code. Think of it as a canvas that I use to "receive" the code I generate from main controller.

Now, when the btn tool is clicked it invokes a function on the btnCTRL, inside this function I call a function inside the tools factory that finally calls the init function of the current clicked tool:

*Why did I choose so? because it allows me better organize my app into small chunks of modules.*

**btnCTRL.js**

```
$scope.toolClicked = function($index) {
    // Launch the ignit function in the main tool factory
    ToolsFactory.ignit(config);
};
```

**tools.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('ToolsFactory', ['Tool1Factory', 'Tool2Factory', 'Tool3Factory',
        function(Tool1Factory, Tool2Factory, Tool3Factory) {
            var toolsAsFactory = {
                't1': Tool1Factory,
                't2': Tool2Factory,
                't3': Tool3Factory
            };
            var ignit = function($config) {
                // Some code to set current clicked tool
                // ...

                // Call the init function on the selected tool
                toolsAsFactory[config.selectedTool].init(config);
            };

            return {
                ignit: ignit
            };
        }
    ]);
```

**tools_1.js**

```
angular.module('Tools')
    .factory('Tool1Factory', function() {

        var init = function($config) {
            // Now adds the html to the iframe!
            //...

        };

        return {
            init: init
        };
    });
```

So.. the question: Since my iframe should not contain no angular code.. Is this a good approach to build such app? Was angular the best choice when it comes to apps with heavy event management?

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to give up the AngularJS approach and use [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/) instead.

My decision was inspired by [this code sample](https://github.com/kristoferjoseph/Building-Reflow-BackboneConf-2013) from Kristof Erjoseph and [this great article](http://www.aaronshekey.com/reflow/) from Adobe designer [Aaron Shekey](http://github.com/aaronshekey/).

I also used [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and its [optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).